# Does the flammable touch result in the Wild Magic Surge table apply to the sorcerer's own possessions?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, wild-magic

In the Sorcerer's Wild Magic Surge table in the 5e PHB, one of the possible results reads

> For the next minute, any flammable object you touch that isn't being
>   worn or carried by another creature bursts into flame.

Given that anything the sorcerer is carrying *is not* being carried or worn by another creature, does this likely mean that the sorcerer's possessions burst into flames? What if after all of the sorcerer's possessions are burned up the sorcerer comes into contact with his/her own skin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### RAW - Yes

As you wrote, the sorcerer is not *another creature*, so this effect must apply to objects he carries/wears.

#### RAI - No

It is probably meant to burn any object not carried or worn by **any** creature. I don't see why this effect should be different for the sorcerer.

**Either way, his skin won't burn**, because it is not an object, but a creature, and creatures are not affected by this effect.

Comment: Can you explain to me what RAW and RAI mean? I'm not familiar with these acronyms.

Comment: RAW = Rules As Written, and RAI = Rules As Intended